# How to navigate web page (input, select, button submit)

Tags: c#, select, button, input, httpclient

I am attempting to automate page search result and put the results in a JSON or CSV file using C#.

The outline is:

1. Go to the web page.
2. Change the date (HTML input modification)
3. Select the city (HTML multi-select modification)
4. Click on the submit button (HTML button named submit)
5. Get the results
6. Click on next to get next page results

I can get the initial page (Step 1), but I don't understand what utilities are available to update the HTML and click on the buttons.

The source code is the following:

```
async static void Function1()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://bla.com/searches/index"))
    {
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
        string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(mycontent);

        // Set the date in the input box:
        //     <input id="sdate" name="sdate" value="10/28/2018" ... />
        // Set value of city in multi-select:
        //     <select id="city" name="city" ...> ...
        // Click on the submit button to get results:
        //     <button type="submit" name="Submit" ...

        // TO DO: Write source code here.


        }
    }
    }
}
```

What could be a good resource or read to figure out how perform the steps that could be done with a mouse and keyboard in a web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main routes here. Either you figure out the protocol the search page is using to communicate with its back-end server and try to communicate with that directly, or you use an automation tool that controls your browser.

The second path is in general easier, and the tool to use is selenium.

I'd suggest you use [Coypu](https://github.com/featurist/coypu), which is a .NET wrapper around selenium. We use it mostly for end-to-end tests, but also occasionally for web automation tasks.

Whatever you can do with mouse and keyboard in a we browser, a Coypu script can do automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it.

Comment: Ok, you were completely correct.  Using this Coypu is super simple.  Once I got the Visual Studio project setup and packages downloaded, it was super simple.